# How to activate "Track changes"-Mode in a word document generated with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

for a recent project I've been generating .docx-Documents via python.
I solved this by using the docxtpl-Package and Word docs as my jinja2-templates so the entire structure of the currently used word template can be maintained.

Now we've discussed that it would be really useful to see it visually in the document if anyone has changed the numbers or texts from the automatically generated document.

My question is - as i unfortunately have found no answers to this yet:

**Is it possible to automatically turn on the "Track changes"-mode within every word document that's being generated?**

The only way of doing, I found so far is this command-line tool - which i couldn't get to work so far and it looks like it has not been maintained the last 6 years:

https://github.com/kopz9999/track-word-changes

I'm currently developing on macOS, but the system will be running on Ubuntu machines. Thus, we can not use the pywin32 module.

Example Code, if it's any help:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import json
import time
from docx2pdf import convert

class DocumentGenerator():
    def render_document(self, customerid, context):
        """
        :params customerid: Engagement number
        :params context: dict containing values for jinja2 template
        :return: returns absolute path of generated document
        _____________________________
        
        """
    
        doc = DocxTemplate("./templates/functional/template.docx")

    
        doc.render(context)
        save_path = f"./demo/{customerid}_generated_document.docx"
    
        doc.save(save_path)
    
        return save_path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn it on in your `template.docx` that you're using as the starting point. The items you generate will not be tracked because `python-docx` doesn't (know how to) do that, so when opened in Word, it should start tracking (enclosing within revision marks) with any edits made to the generated version.

This will bear testing of course, but I'm betting this will work fine. Make sure to clear any revision marks in `template.docx` before turning on "track-revisions" so you don't capture any "old" ones.

Comment: It can be so simple.. 
Tested this and it works for the general purpose, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can add <w:trackRevisions/> to the Word document xml settings file using `lxml`. It takes a few steps.

First you need to access and revise the settings file of the Word document.

```
track_off = f'\path\document_name.docx' # here's your word document
def get_settings_file(filename):
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    xmlcontent = zfile.read('word/settings.xml')
    return xmlcontent

stgs = get_settings_file(track_off)
stgs_xml = etree.fromstring(stgs)
```

Then you need to create the new xml to insert:

```
xml_to_insert = etree.fromstring('<w:trackRevisions xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"/>')
```

Now you insert the new xml into the settings xml. This is the way I did it, but it's probably more straightforward than iterating over the simple settings xml tree:

```
for node in stgs_xml.xpath(f'//w:settings', namespaces={'w':"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"}):
    node.insert(2, xml_to_insert) # the 2 places the xml in the right location in the tree
```

Then you create a string version of your new xml:

```
stgs_new = etree.tostring(stgs_xml)
# Do the below line if you'd like to see how the xml has changed
print(etree.tostring(stgs_xml, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Finally, you need to put this new stgs file into a word document. I create a whole new word document based on the original but with track changes on.

```
zin = zipfile.ZipFile(track_off, 'r')
zout = zipfile.ZipFile(f'\path\document_name_trackon.docx', 'w')
for item in zin.infolist():
    original_xml = zin.read(item.filename)
    if(item.filename == 'word/settings.xml'):
        zout.writestr(item.filename, stgs_new)
    else:
        zout.writestr(item.filename, original_xml)
zin.close()
zout.close()
```

This solution has worked for me, but I do worry that it may cause issues on Word documents that have very complex settings.xml files. I haven't come across any issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Linux of MacOS, you can just use the resource at [here](https://github.com/kopz9999/track-word-changes). It works great.

To use it in your Python script, you will have to use `subprocess library` of course. For instance,

```
 subprocess.Popen(['track_word --revision_track=true '+your_input_docx_file], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```